# Xpath Web scrape

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

```
<a class="support" style="letter-spacing: -1px" href="/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/List/updates" data-executing="0">I'm random</a>
```

I'm trying to scrape the above link attribute using xpath, the link text `"I'm random"` is always changing. The rest remains the same. The `"I'm random"` text is what I'm looking to scrape.

I don't really understand xpath, How would I pull just the inner text? I have tried:

```
string html = Web.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var Attributes = new List<string>();
var Randomtxt = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[‌​@href]");
if (Randomtxt != null)
{
    foreach (var contents in Randomtxt)
    {
        string href = contents.InnerHtml;
        var parts = href.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length > 1)
        {
            Attributes.Add(parts[1]);
        }
    }
    Attribute.DataSource = Attributes;
}
```

But it returns nothing at all. How would I go about getting just the inner text.

Comment: [ref:](http://nyqui.st/parsing-html-in-c)`htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")`, then for each node, call `node.InnerHtml`.

Comment: Explain the defining characteristics of the link you want to get. Are there any, except "has a `href`"? (Besides, XPath isn't really hard. Have you tried to pick it up for a few hours or have you given up straight-away?)

Comment: I'm just starting it, The part I want is the random text. I don't need the href link. Only the text that is generated

Comment: You did not describe the *defining characteristic* of the link you want to get. I suppose is more than one link on that page, and without any further definition *all of them* contain random text. So how do you recognize the one are you interested in? (Or do really you want to get every link?)

Comment: Apart from that, when you are just starting it, maybe working through a few tutorials and trying to find out yourself first would be in order?

Comment: Because the link I'm looking for is the only one on the page tagged `<a` I can pull the link to the html posted in the topic. Its the text I cant figure out.

Comment: What do you think `ExecuteJavascriptWithResult()` does? Why do you use it?`

Comment: I use that because Document is not recognized in awesomium web controller. It allows me to use javascript to find my buttons.

Comment: Maybe. But... either the HTML Agility Pack is your parser, then why don't you use it to parse the document? Or Awesomeium.NET is your parser, then why don't you use *that* to find your link text? What's wrong with `.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent");`? There is absolutely no reason to use both frameworks.

Comment: I'll say this then I'm done with this post. Using that also returned nothing. Yes I'm sure I have everything written correctly. I'm also 100% sure that is the only button on my page because I created it to test. Thanks for trying so hard to make it known that I'm new to this. I'm trying to learn this, remember you were once new to this also. That's all I'm saying on this matter. I'll teach my self have a nice night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not xpath but this works for what I wanna do, problem solved.

```
    List<string> Attributes = new List<string>();
    string html = Web.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
    MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"data-executing=\s*(.+?)\s*/a>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

    foreach (Match m in m1)
     {
      string new = m.Groups[1].Value;
      Attributes.Add(new);
     }
    Attribute.DataSource = Attributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

first find the single node

var Randomtxt = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[‌​@class='support']");

then pull the inner text

string value = Randomtxt.Innertext;

Comment: `//*[‌​@class='support']/a` will not find anything.

Comment: I can pull the links, The part I cant seem to get is the random text that is generated.